# How to send a base64 image using aiogram?

Tags: base64, aiogram

I need to send an image to the user that is encoded in base64. I am new to aiogram and python.`media = types.InputMediaPhoto("base64://"+photo, caption=caption)#This bullshit doesn't work.`

Is there a way to bypass saving as jpeg?